# Cannot return a value from Run function when using Azure Function V1 ServiceBusTrigger in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

is it possible to return a value from the Run method when using an Azure Function ServiceBusTrigger V1 in Visual Studio 2017. For example am I able to do either of the below? 
At this point, the "Run" method is only returning a void.

```
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("testqueue1")]BrokeredMessage message, ILogger log, IAsyncCollector<string> outputString)
        {
         outputString = "test string";
return outputString;
        }
    }

[FunctionName("Function1")]
            public static string Run([ServiceBusTrigger("testqueue1")]BrokeredMessage message, ILogger log)
            {
             outputString = "test string";
    return outputString;
            }
        }
```

regards

Kojo

Comment: What do you want to return in the trigger? For Azure Function, the return value is supposed to be a output binding.

Comment: i wanted to verify some of the value of the outputs in my unit tests. I thought  the output bindings were dynamically generated when you compile or run the azure function. Can you manually create the return value?